# How to update git on mac (it was preinstalled?)

Tags: git

I have a mac, git came installed with it. How do I go about getting the latest? (I'm currently running 1.7.3.1).

Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend to use homebrew: http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely didn't come with Git preinstalled, but you probably got it if/when you installed the developer tools.

Felix's comment is spot-on though, [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is the way to go for git and many other Unix packages on OS X.

Comment: fwiw I downloaded from here [http://git-scm.com/download/mac] and just ran the .dmg file. The readme says if upgrading to run the uninstall script, but I did not do that. Running the dmg seems to have worked fine, terminal reports git was updated. Thank you